Windows Explorer says internal HDD is read-only, everything else says it's not, how to fix?
I've been searching a few days for answers but I didn't see anyone else with this particular problem.
I have an internal 4TB WD Blue SATA drive purchased in 2018. I moved this drive to a new build in 2021. Whenever I want to copy files to it, Windows says it needs admin permission because the drive is "read-only". Right clicking on folders on the drive to bring up the Properties shows the Read-only boxed checked. If I uncheck it and click OK, it immediately reverts back to read-only.
The ACL for the drive is below.
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(OI)(CI)(F)
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(F)

Security in Properties shows everyone has full control permissions for the drive with everything marked Allow except for Special Permissions.
I updated the Owner of the drive to my user account on the new build and applied the change to all subfolders and files, but it didn't help.
The Advanced Security Settings for the drive: 
The Advanced Security Settings for the folder: 
DiskPart shows "Current Read-only State : No" for the disk attributes. Also, Disk Management shows the drive as Online, not read-only.
There is nothing in the registry named WriteProtect.

I tried disabling my antivirus.
I deleted the driver and rebooted Windows.
I ran chkdsk. No problems were found.
I ran SpinRite 6.1 release 3 on level 5 on this drive to thoroughly find and fix any errors on the disk. No problems were found.

At every stage I attempted unchecking Read-only from the Windows Explorer folder properties, but the folders always reverts back to Read-only immediately.
Am I missing something obvious? Any ideas for what to try next?

SpinRite 6.1 is incompatible with 4TB drives unless you are using 6.1 Release number 3. Can you provide the ACL for the drive.  We need Security which shows the group or users with access and the advanced security settings for the folder. [Edit] your question instead of submitting an unformatted comment

instead of text please provide screenshots of the ACL, specifically, the advanced security settings.

The owner of the folder doesn’t exist on the system. You should change the owner of the folder to that of a user that does exist on the system. This is the reason the read-only checkbox cannot be changed

@JoepvanSteen I'm not sure I understand, what should I do for the drive? I updated the owner of the drive and applied to all subfolders and files, as the quoted part of your comment states. I used the "Replace all child object permission entries" checkbox in Advanced Security Settings to do it. Is there another way to do this?

Just added an image for D:

I suspect you have a file system problem.  Since you have read access I would copy the files to a new backup drive, format the original, then restore the files to the newly formatted partition.

@JoepvanSteen While in Properties > Security? No show advanced on that path.
